# How to disable dropdown

Tags: jquery, html

I have 5 dropdown lists where each has *None option* whereby when user clicks the *None option*, the selected *None option* dropdown will be disabled.

```js
$("#general").change(function() {
  if ($("option:selected", this).val() === "null1")
    $(this).attr("disabled", "true");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mt-3 px-3 form-group row">
  <label for="inputGeneral" class="col-sm-3 mt-2 col-form-label">General</label>
  <select id="general" onchange="valChange(value);" class="col-lg-3 mt-2 px-3 selectpicker" name="usageGeneral" multiple data-live-search="true">
    <option value="null1">None</option>
    <option>Network Login</option>
    <option>Email</option>
    <option>Integrated Management System</option>
    <option value="other1">Others</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Others" style="display: none; padding: 0.5%; height: 0.5%;" id="textbox1">
</div>
```

Comment: What is `valChange()` supposed to do?

Comment: Your snippet works when I remove `onchange="valChange()"`

Comment: @Barmar onchange="valChange(value); is for my 'Others option' whereby when user clicks it, a textbox will be appeared next to my dropdown

Comment: u can simply use css disable

Comment: Why don't you put that into the `$("#general").change()` function instead of having two different functions?

Comment: Also the line:  $(this).attr("disabled", "true"); the truth value is boolean, not a string. You can write it as  $(this).attr("disabled", true);

Comment: @RohanRao A non-empty string is truthy, so it will work that way as well.

Comment: What problem are you having? Your code works when I try it.

Comment: @Barmar When I click the 'None option' the dropdown list is supposed to be disabled but right now 'None option' could be selected along with other options.

Comment: It works here: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/jzh8u5xL/6/

Comment: @Mia will it *multiple* or *single* selection? I think this should be single selection because of what will happen if multi select and also other select then what will next step?

Comment: @RaeeshAlam This should be a multi select dropdown list and I have 5 dropdowns in total. When I try to run the code and connect it to database, multi select dropdown list and 'Others option' run well but not for 'None option' as it still could be selected with other options in that particular dropdown.

Comment: @Mia You mean that when you choose `None` then all selected dropdown should be unselect and also when you choose `Other` then all selected dropdown should be unselect and bottom input field should be appear right?

Comment: @RaeeshAlam When I select _None_ option on the first dropdown, only the first dropdown will be entirely disabled. But the other dropdowns are still active. Also, when I select _Others_ option for 1 particular dropdown, a textbox will appear and same goes to when I click _Other_ option on the other dropdowns.

Comment: @RaeeshAlam I want to ask the code Javascript you sent earlier, it works on first dropdown but not for second dropdown. How do I do it? If, else if?

Comment: @Mia You mean that you have 5 different drop-down with different `ids` and `values`?

Comment: @RaeeshAlam Yes, different ids and values.

Comment: @Mia You can check my updated snippet for more dropdown with common script with help of `data-selection` attribute and in this `data-selection` attribute to passing hidden input field `id`.

Comment: @RaeeshAlam if I want to make it dynamic, should I change <option value="other1">Others</option> to <option input="other1">Others</option> and repeat by changing other2, other3 for every dropdowns?

Comment: @Mia No, don't need to change `<option value="other1">Others</option>` just need to change `id` of hidden `input type` for Insert others. Like for 1st dropdown `data-selection="#textbox1"` then 1st hidden input id should be `textbox1` if for 2nd dropdown `data-selection="#textbox2"` then 2nd hidden input id should be `textbox2` and so on...

Comment: @RaeeshAlam I am sorry but why do my selection as I select more than 1 option it only returns 1 latest selection to my database? (Eg: I select Network Login then Email) and when I check my database it only stores Email which is the latest one I clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `selectpicker` plugin so you need to use `destroy`+`refresh` method to set value with conditionally check on selection `drop-down`.
*Note: Used `data-selection="#hiddeninputid"` for more drop-down and write common script for all.*
Doc: https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/methods/#selectpickerdestroy

I hope this will help you lot.

```js
var selectedOption = [];
$(document).on('change', '[data-selection]', function(e){ 
  //Get hidden input for others 
  var getHiddenId = $(this).attr('data-selection');
  var currentValues = $(this).val();
  var currentSelection;
  if (selectedOption) {  
    currentSelection = currentValues.filter(function(el) {
      return selectedOption.indexOf(el) < 0;
    });
  }
  selectedOption = $(this).val();
  // If user select None
  if (currentSelection=='null1') {
    $(this).val('null1');
    $(this).selectpicker('destroy').selectpicker('refresh');
    $(getHiddenId).hide();
  }
  // If not selected None
  if (currentSelection!='null1') {
    $(getHiddenId).hide();
    const index = selectedOption.indexOf('null1');
    if (index > -1) {
     //Remove null1 from array
     selectedOption.splice(index, 1);
    }
    const index2 = selectedOption.indexOf('other1');
    if (index2 > -1) {
      //If other1 is exist in array then appear input field
      $(getHiddenId).fadeIn();
    }
    $(this).val(selectedOption);
    $(this).selectpicker('refresh');
    //If selected Others
    if (currentSelection=='other1') {
      $(this).selectpicker('destroy').selectpicker('refresh');
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Selectpicker Plugins (CSS+JS) -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.9/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.9/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<div class="container py-3">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
   <div class="form-group row">
     <label for="inputGeneral" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label text-left text-sm-right">General #1:</label>
     <div class="col-sm-6">
      <select data-selection="#textbox1" class="form-control selectpicker" name="usageGeneral" multiple data-live-search="true">
        <option value="null1">None</option>
        <option>Network Login</option>
        <option>Email</option>
        <option>Integrated Management System</option>
        <option value="other1">Others</option>
      </select>
      <input type="text" class="form-control my-2" placeholder="Others" style="display: none" id="textbox1">
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group row">
     <label for="inputGeneral" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label text-left text-sm-right">General #2:</label>
     <div class="col-sm-6">
      <select data-selection="#textbox2" class="form-control selectpicker" name="usageGeneral" multiple data-live-search="true">
        <option value="null1">None</option>
        <option>Network Login</option>
        <option>Email</option>
        <option>Integrated Management System</option>
        <option value="other1">Others</option>
      </select>
      <input type="text" class="form-control my-2" placeholder="Others" style="display: none" id="textbox2">
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group row">
     <label for="inputGeneral" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label text-left text-sm-right">General #3:</label>
     <div class="col-sm-6">
      <select data-selection="#textbox3" class="form-control selectpicker" name="usageGeneral" multiple data-live-search="true">
        <option value="null1">None</option>
        <option>Network Login</option>
        <option>Email</option>
        <option>Integrated Management System</option>
        <option value="other1">Others</option>
      </select>
      <input type="text" class="form-control my-2" placeholder="Others" style="display: none" id="textbox3">
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group row">
     <label for="inputGeneral" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label text-left text-sm-right">General #4:</label>
     <div class="col-sm-6">
      <select data-selection="#textbox4" class="form-control selectpicker" name="usageGeneral" multiple data-live-search="true">
        <option value="null1">None</option>
        <option>Network Login</option>
        <option>Email</option>
        <option>Integrated Management System</option>
        <option value="other1">Others</option>
      </select>
      <input type="text" class="form-control my-2" placeholder="Others" style="display: none" id="textbox4">
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group row">
     <label for="inputGeneral" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label text-left text-sm-right">General #5:</label>
     <div class="col-sm-6">
      <select data-selection="#textbox5" class="form-control selectpicker" name="usageGeneral" multiple data-live-search="true">
        <option value="null1">None</option>
        <option>Network Login</option>
        <option>Email</option>
        <option>Integrated Management System</option>
        <option value="other1">Others</option>
      </select>
      <input type="text" class="form-control my-2" placeholder="Others" style="display: none" id="textbox5">
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove the valChange attribute on your drop-down mark up. You already have a listener on your jquery script.

```js
$("#general").change(function() {
  if ($("option:selected", this).val() === "null1")
    $(this).attr("disabled", "true");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mt-3 px-3 form-group row">
  <label for="inputGeneral" class="col-sm-3 mt-2 col-form-label">General</label>
  <select id="general" class="col-lg-3 mt-2 px-3 selectpicker" name="usageGeneral" multiple data-live-search="true">
    <option value="null1">None</option>
    <option>Network Login</option>
    <option>Email</option>
    <option>Integrated Management System</option>
    <option value="other1">Others</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Others" style="display: none; padding: 0.5%; height: 0.5%;" id="textbox1">
</div>
```